# Scheme using map on arguments with different size

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

How do I accomplish something like this in scheme?
an example input would be

```
(scalar-mult '(1 2) 2)
```

with the output

```
'(2 4)
```

here's what I've tried so far:

```
(define (scalar-mult vec s)
  (map (λ (vec s) (* s vec)) vec s))
```

I've seen a different similar thread recommend concat and repeat but that doesn't seem to work on scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l` is the list, `m` the multiplier and `e` an element of the list.

Try this:

```
(define scalar-mult
  (lambda (l m)
    (map (lambda (e)
           (* e m))
         l)))
```

The function `map` takes two arguments. First a function which gets applied to each element of a list and second a list.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is iterate over the list elements of `2`, which is ridiculous. If you want `2` to be available as a variable just don't mention it and pass it like this:

```
(define (scalar-mult vec s)
  (map (λ (vec) (* s vec)) vec))
```

To answer the question when lists are of different size:

`map` in the Scheme standard requires that the list arguments are exactly the same size, however you have [SRFI-1](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) that works as if the lists all have the same number of elements as the shortest list.

```
#!r6rs

(import (except (rnrs base) map for-each)
        (srfi :1))

(map (lambda (n1 n2) (+ n1 n2)) 
     (circular-list 1 2) ; infinite list with 1, 2 repeating
     '(2 3 4 5))
; ==> (3 5 5 7)
```